# Determining if a string is only digits using a function

Tags: python, string, function

I need to write a function that will give true or false when the user inputs a string depending on if it is all digits or not.  This is what I have so far, but im not sure what is wrong

```
def string():
    st=input('Enter string: ')
    if st.isdigit():
        stc='True'
    else:
        stc='False'


        return stc


n = int(input("Number of runs: "))
for i in range(n):
    print()
    stc=string()
    if stc=='True':
        print('True')
    else:
        print('False')
```

Comment: You only `return` in the negative case (indentation matters!) and why return a string, not a Boolean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you return stc only in the `else`

correct would be:

```
def string():
    st=input('Enter string: ')
    if st.isdigit():
        stc='True'
    else:
        stc='False'
    return stc
```

but instead of using strings representing boolean values, why don't you use directly `True` and `False`?

```
def string():
    st=input('Enter string: ')
    if st.isdigit():
        stc=True
    else:
        stc=False
    return stc
```

then you can change the if condition as well and everything will be a bit nicer:

```
...
stc=string()
if stc:
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

**Update:**

As noted in the comments, you could also just totally skip the if condition and only return `st.isdigit()` like this:

```
def string():
    st=input('Enter string: ')
    return st.isdigit()
```

keep in mind that now you get a boolean value (`True/False`) as return, so you'll need to adapt the if-condition

Comment: The `if st.isdigit(): stc=True else: stc=False` is poor style, `return st.isdigit()` will yield the same result.

Comment: Indeed, the entire function could be written `string = str.isdigit`.